# How to autofill user and slug fields in django form

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, slug

I need two of the three form fields to be filled in automatically before submitting to the database. Slug is supposed to be filled based on test_name, and user have to be filled based on data about the current user.

Now I can submit the form, but the database entry will not be created.

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model): 
    test_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_index=True, verbose_name='Test name') 
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, verbose_name='URL') 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column="user", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

forms.py

```
class AddTestForm(forms.ModelForm): 
    class Meta: 
        model = Test 
        fields = ['test_name', 'slug', 'author']
```

views.py

```
def ask_test_name(request): 
    form = AddTestForm(request.POST) 
 
    if form.is_valid(): 
        test = form.save(False) 
        test.slug = slugify(test.test_name) 
        test.author = request.user 
        test.save() 
 
    return render(request, 'app/ask_test_name.html', {'form': form})
```

ask_test_name.html

```
<form action="{% url 'ask_test_name' %}" method="post"> 
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <p><input type="text" name="test_name" required></p> 
    <p><input type="hidden" name="slug"></p> 
    <p><input type="hidden" name="author"></p> 
    <p><button type="submit">Create</button></p> 
</form>
```

*Updated*

It seems to me the problem is that the html does not see what model I want to use, but I don't know how to solve it here, I need two fields to be hidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `slug` and `author` from the `fields` in `forms.py` and don't include them in your HTML form. That should do the trick. You're only hitting the DB after already assigning values to `slug` and `author`, so that shouldn't throw an error.